# Disable CSS link for 1 second after it has been clicked

Tags: javascript, css

I'm trying to have a CSS link disabled for 1 second after it has been clicked.

I have tried this without success;

In the header:

```
<script type="text/javascript">
$(function() {
    $("#link").click(function() {
        $("#link").attr("disabled", "disabled");
        setTimeout(function() {
            $("#link").removeAttr("disabled");      
        }, 2000);
    });
});
</script>
```

Html:

```
<a href="#" class="link">the link text</a>
```

CSS:

```
.link:diabled {
some values here.. }
```

Comment: What's your problem with the code? Or could you set up a JSFiddle to demonstrate?

Comment: is `.link:diabled` correct? (diabled != disabled)

Comment: You should define "disabled". Do you mean that you can't even click it, or that it simply does nothing when clicked?

Comment: @jackJoe I suppose this was a typo when writing.

Comment: I don't think href's have a "disabled" attribute. You'll need to remove the href.

Comment: @showdev you can use the attribute, it only won't trigger any special functionality. See also my answer below.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

There are quite a few problems here:

1. You are using `#` (the ID selector), but your html is using classes.
2. `<a>` does not have a disabled attribute
3. If it did, you would probably want to use `.prop` instead of `.attr`
4. If you change code to use classes, `$(".link").prop("disabled", true)` would affect *all* anchors, so you should probably use `this`.
5. Because `disabled` does not exist for `<a>`, the `:disabled` selector does not seem to work for CSS.

A working solution would be something like this:

```
$(".link").click(function() {
    var $this = $(this);
    $this.addClass('disabled');
    setTimeout(function() {
        $this.removeClass('disabled');
    }, 2000);
});

$(document).on('click', '.disabled', function (e) {
    e.preventDefault();
});
```

http://jsfiddle.net/ExplosionPIlls/PaYcc/

Comment: +1 better presented than mine and provides the fixed code. I just was about to write a jsfiddle, but you've already done it ;-)

Comment: double click gives problems though i have a solution below

Answer (score 4):

You have a `class="link"`, but with `$("#link")` you are addressing the `id` called `link`.

So write `$(".link")` everywhere instead of `$("#link")`.

By the way: with `.link:disabled` you won't address the link as this only works on inputs and buttons. If you need to address it, use `.link[disabled="disabled"] { ... }` or even better add a class to it called `disabled_link` and then do in CSS `.disabled_link { ... }`.

Comment: The OP could always take the easy way out and do `$(this)`. :P Good catch though...+1

Comment: @War10ck At least in the outer function call, he needs to address it explicitely.

Comment: Correct. Inside though he could create a reference `var $this = $(this)` and reference that from there on out rather than re-traversing the DOM multiple times.

Answer (score 3):

`'link'` is a **class** and you are using it as **ID**. Do `$('.link')` instead of `$('#link')`.

Answer (score 0):

I think this approach works better. The other allows you to click the link multiple times and mess up the setTimeout this unbinds the event and then re-attaches the event after the setTimeout ex: double click the link

```
$(".link").click(linkBind);
function linkBind(){
    var $this = $(this);
        $this.addClass('disabled');
        $this.unbind('click');
        setTimeout(function() {
            $this.removeClass('disabled');
            $this.bind('click', linkBind);
        }, 2000);
}

$(document).on('click', '.disabled', function (e) {
    e.preventDefault();
});
```

http://jsfiddle.net/PaYcc/1/